# Why won't RHC tell me what all apps are available?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I write `rhc apps` and the reply is...

```
...
  Deployment: auto (on git push)

  php-5.4 (PHP 5.4)
  -----------------
    Gears: 1 small

←[32mYou have access to 2 applications.←[0m
```

but it won't tell me their names.  How can I get a verbatim list of the application names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange.. ! but when i tried my machine with that command i got the list of apps .

Try these commands also

```
rhc apps -l <your login>

rhc apps --mine
```